# What is the Vista equivalent of XP's 'at' command?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, update

I'm trying to automate some jobs and am using the 'at' command on Windows XP. However, Vista doesn't have this.

What do I use instead? It needs to be usable from a batch script as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[schtasks](http://www.ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html) is 'at' on steroids for Windows.

From the [Windows Vista Task Scheduler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/appcompat/aa906020.aspx) page:

***Scripting and Command Line Options.*** Improving the user experience is one of the main goals of the Windows Vista Task Scheduler. For IT professionals that prefer to use a command line tool instead of GUI, the schtasks.exe command line utility has been extended to cover all the new functionality added for Windows Vista. The application programming interface (API) is now also scriptable.

[A hack exists](http://windowsitpro.com/article/articleid/76639/jsi-tip-5335-can-i-use-the-windows-xp-command-line-scheduler-in-windows-2000.html) for running it on Windows 2000.

Comment: Does it work on Vista/7? Or even 2k for that matter?